# PanelClass for MatDialogConfig is being added to the wrong element. How can I resolve this?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to remove the padding around mat-dialog-container by adding a custom class to the dialog like so.

Custom class

```
.custom-dialog-container {
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Opening the dialog

```
myFunction(data) {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.data = {
      data: data
    }
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.width = "auto";
    dialogConfig.height = "auto";
    dialogConfig.panelClass = "custom-dialog-container";
    let dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(DialogComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

However, when inspecting the html custom-dialog-container is not being added to mat-dialog-container, but to the parent div instead

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane custom-dialog-container"
    style="max-width: 80vw; pointer-events: auto; width: auto; height: auto; position: 
    static;">
</div>
    <mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true"
        class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c6-3 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer 
        ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"
        id="mat-dialog-0" role="dialog" style="transform: none;">
```

How can I resolve this issue? Is there another method to remove padding on mat-dialog-container?

Comment: Did you try `.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container { padding: 0px; }`?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Añadir un comentarioEscribe aquí Campo requerido 0/200CancelarAceptar

Aulaplaneta script
you can youse it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).